# Generalized Möbius Inversion formulae

Tags: combinatorics, mobius-inversion

I am having as problem with inverting a relation of the form

$f(i)=\sum_{j=0}^i g(i,j)h(j)$

I would like to have h in terms of f and g. I know that if my formula was of the form $f(i)=∑_j^ih(j)$ I could just use a generalized Möbius inversion formula, but since g depends on both i and j I don't think the method applies. Is there a more general one? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: $g(i,j)=\binom{i}{j}$

Comment: @BarryCipra Oops, thank you!

Comment: We must assume the values $g(i,j)$ are known, and that $g(j,j)\neq 0$.  Think of rewriting this in matrix notation.

Comment: @hardmath See my edit. It gives a triangular matrix and so the inverse is calculable but not particularly pleasant to do. But perhaps this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you need the diagonal entries to be nonzero so the triangular matrix is invertible.  Are you specifying the particular $g(i,j)$ in the edit?

Comment: @hardmath $g(i,j)=\binom{n-i}{j'}$ where $j'=\min(j,n-j)$. These are all non-zero and so the matrix is indeed invertible.

Comment: Is there a tacit assumption here that $i\le n$?

Comment: I hate to be a nitpicker, but in the summation $j\le i$ naturally, so $n-j \ge n-i$.  Thus $i=n-1$ and $j=2$ could lead to $\binom{1}{2}$ for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, $i\leq n$.

Comment: @hardmath No, thank you for nitpicking! It is useful. I have been staring at these coefficients now for ages and can't see what has gone wrong, I think I'll get it tomorrow. It is just simple counting, no deep meaning to them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll look forward to it.  One suspects the coefficients might be affected by the earlier swapping of $i,j$ roles in summation.

Comment: @hardmath Turns out $g(i,j)=\binom{i}{i-j}$. This actually works now! Sorry for the slow reply

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your previous Edit, and making $g(i,j)$ the equivalent $\binom{i}{j}$ to what you've revised it.